# Trying to understand family tree

Tags: family-tree

I’m a college student that came across this family tree diagram and am trying to interpret it. My current interpretation puts almost every individual in the diagram to having either incest, an affair, or being underage.

Please help me find where I’m flawed.

[image]

Comment: Please explain specifically which individuals appear to have incest or affairs. Obviously this is not a professional diagram, but it seems quite clear that the people shown in this tree are parents, step-parents, grandparents, and half-siblings.

Comment: well, it is the “me” person

Comment: also the ages just don’t make sense so i was hoping it would have been more on my understanding than the diagram

Comment: "Me" has two half siblings on his dad's side (age 9 and 14). "Me" has one half sibling on his mum's side (age 13).

Comment: You would need to do some research to determine whether the ages in this diagram are incorrect. Agreed, some of the kids were born when parents were very young, according to this diagram. As this is a casual diagram drawn by a kid it is most likely that some of the ages are just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The ages are suspect, but the relationships are somewhat clear.

For the purposes of the chart, I've assumed that the year is 2024 and that the people marked as X are recently deceased. The charts below were produced by RootsMagic 8.

<sub>*For the people with two marriages, I would prefer to have the common person (e.g. Libed in the first chart and Layla in the second) in the middle with the first spouse above and the second below, but that's not the way RootsMagic did it.*</sub>

Mohamad (b. 1964) and Halima (b. 1963) had a son, Libed (b. 1988).
Libed m. 1999 Layla (b. 1991) and had child Me.
Libed and Layla divorced in 2004.
Libed m. second Handi (b. 1995) and had son Mohamad (b. 2010) and daughter Sara (b. 2015).

[image: Descendant chart for Mohamad]

Ali (b. 1944) and Xowa (b. 1948) had a daughter Layla (b. 1991).
Layla m. 1999 Libed, had child Me, and divorced 2004, as above.
Layla m. second Abdi (b. 1984) and had son Zaki (b. 2011).

[image: Descendant chart for Ali]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Me is living with his mother.
Crated this with Family Tree JS
[image: me living with mom]

[image: my dad's family]